# InetAddress.getLocalHost() is always crashing

Tags: android, network-programming

I'm developing an android app which I want it to display all the IP addresses on the network, I have used it in a java application which works well but when I use it in an android app it crashes when it arrives at `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`, can this work on an android app or is there another way to do it?

code

```
InetAddress localhost = null;

    try {

        localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); // it crashes here
        System.out.println("after");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("the application stoped here");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("3");
    // this code assumes IPv4 is used
    byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 254; i++) {
        ip[3] = (byte) i;

        InetAddress address = null;
        try {
            address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PingThread p = new PingThread(address);
        p.start();
    }
```

Comment: See the logcat to see the likely NetworkOnMainThreadException. Post the stacktrace here, too.

Comment: what you trying to do

Comment: if you playing with sockets the use socket.getInetAddress();

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this problem by adding this to your code before the try/catch:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

...and this to your AndroidManifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
```

Refer to the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) for more details about the StrictMode.